# Understanding Postfix and Courier IMAP

Tags: email, mysql, imap, postfix, mail-server

I'm setting up my own mail server, and I'm very new at this... and I'm getting lost. I need your help in determining some parameters the way I know them already, because the configuration is huge.

So, I followed [this tutorial](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/#intro), which is extremely detailed from the application side, but very unexplained.

I finished now the part up until the end of Courier IMAP, and now I have to start with Advanced Mail Server, and I have some questions there for the experts.

So, what I understand is that if the MX record is set for a domain, then e-mails are forwarded to some IP address. Then, if a mail server is open (postfix), it receives the e-mail, confirms that the e-mail address exists at its database, and then accepts it and saves it somewhere on the server.

My questions about this are:

Where are the e-mails saved on the server? and where is the database of users with their e-mails which is in the form name@web.com? and is that managed with MySQL somehow? Please explain this in a way related to the tutorial.

Then, after the e-mail is saved, Courier IMAP accesses the same place where Postfix saved the e-mail using the same user database Postfix used, and retrieves your e-mails.

My questions about this are:

Is the process correct? And again, where is the user database in the setup I made according to the tutorial?

Thank you for any efforts.

Answer (score -1):

emails are saved either in the either in /var/mail or in /var/spool/mail; the long answer is that it depends on your Postfix configuration."

Every user have its mailspool like

> /var/spool/mail/$USER

If you are using the mbox format for inboxes, all the mails will be in a same file inside the mail folder. If you are using maildir format, then separate files will be there for each emails.

We can change/convert mbox to maildir by configuring postfix.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how does it classify users there?